# SELECT id from 'persone' LEFT JOIN time on persone.id=time.p' at line 2

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a page for manage `persone` for an ivent and I get 2 errors

**1st Error:**

Every time when i refresh the page i find an empty data in my db .

**2nd Error**:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(SELECT id from 'persone' LEFT JOIN time on persone.id=time.p'
>   at line 2

thanks for help

this is my code

```
<?php

include('config.php');
$nom = (!empty($_POST['nom']))?$_POST['nom']:""; 
$prenom = (!empty($_POST['prenom']))?$_POST['prenom']:""; 
$cin = (!empty($_POST['cin']))?$_POST['cin']:""; 
$tel= (!empty($_POST['tel']))?$_POST['tel']:""; 
$cat= (!empty($_POST['categore']))?$_POST['categore']:""; 
$date= (!empty($_POST['d_donation']))?$_POST['d_donation']:"";
$time=(!empty($_POST['time']))?$_POST['time']:"";
$sql="INSERT INTO persone(nom, prenom, cin, tel, categore ,d_donation) value ('$nom','$prenom', '$cin','$tel','$cat','$date')
            (SELECT id from 'persone' 
                            LEFT JOIN time 
                                on persone.id=time.p_id)";

if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
    }
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this code `(SELECT id from 'persone' 
                            LEFT JOIN time 
                                on persone.id=time.p_id)`. This is not required, if you are trying to just insert records.

Comment: You want insert the data or update the data for persone.id????

Comment: Quotes are for strings, backticks are for tables/columns. You are open to SQL injections. Put all the values into the `select` or put the `select` as a sub query in the `values`.... Although it actually looks like the number of columns and values you have match up.. Are you trying to insert the person's id somewhere or select that after?

Comment: i have 2 table 
persone
id/nom/prenom/cin/tel/categore/d_donation
time
id/how_many/p_id
i need to get the id from person and insert into time in p_id

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to remove *single* quotes in

```
Select Table 
       (SELECT id 
        FROM persone 
        LEFT JOIN time 
        ON persone.id=time.p_id)
```